# Unable to pause activity, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid Index 0,size is 0

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm save ListView information using `onSaveInstanceState()` , `onRestoreInstanceState()` incase the user change orientation.
However when the user move to other activity I want the ListView information to be removed so I use `clear();` method but for some reason I get error using `clear();` method.

LogCat :

```
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.project/com.example.project.InternetActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at com.example.project.InternetActivity.onSaveInstanceState(InternetActivity.java:68)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1036)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3330)
07-25 10:00:59.326: E/AndroidRuntime(940):  ... 12 more
```

InternetActivity.java - I didn't add all the .java file because it is very long. Instand I just added the problem.

```
package com.example.project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class InternetActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{

    final static String TAG = "InternetActivity";


    static List<Movie> moviesList = new ArrayList<Movie>(); 
    ArrayAdapter<Movie> adapter;
    static public Movie[] moviesArray;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

        ListView list = getListView();  
        Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnCancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnGo);
        goButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Movie>(this, R.layout.itemlist_movie_internet, R.id.textTitle, moviesList);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++) 
        {
            Movie m = moviesList.get(i);
            outState.putString("title"+""+i,m.getSubject());
            outState.putString("body"+""+i,m.getBody());
            outState.putString("url"+""+i,m.getUrl());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {       
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++) 
        {
            state.getString("title"+""+i);
            state.getString("body"+""+i);
            state.getString("url"+""+i);        
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.BtnCancel: //Move back to main activity
            moviesList.clear(); //PROBLEM
            Intent intent = new Intent(InternetActivity.this, MainActivity.class);                      
            startActivity(intent);          
            break;
            default:
            break;
     }
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not initialize `moviesArray`. So either initialize it before using it or to get elements from `moviesList` in your code change

`moviesArray.length` to `moviesList.size()`,i.e.

Change

```
 for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++)
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++)
```

And check the size of `moviesList` before clear it as

```
if(moviesList != null && moviesList.size() > 0)
  moviesList.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the length of moviesArray, but try to get elements from moviesList. Perhaps you want to use moviesList.length instead?

Here is the offending code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++) 
    {
        Movie m = moviesList.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

"**moviesList.size()**" in your code instaed of **movieArray.length**

```
for (int i = 0; i < moviesList.size(); i++) 
        {
            Movie m = moviesList.get(i);
            outState.putString("title"+""+i,m.getSubject());
            outState.putString("body"+""+i,m.getBody());
            outState.putString("url"+""+i,m.getUrl());
        }
```